# How to center the div in div without margin tag?

Tags: asp.net, css

I would like to know how to center a container (div). I have used `margin:auto` / `margin:0 auto;` / `margin-left:auto;` / `margin-right:auto;` but all of these are not working.

And what is the exact use of position tag, and when do we have to use it?

CSS (from comments):

```
body 
{ 
    background-image:url('images/bgbody.jpg'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-size:cover; 
    margin:0 0 0 0; 
    padding:0 0 0 0; 
} 
.main /*main container*/ 
{ 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 auto ; 
    width: 1550px; 
    /*float:left; width:100%; height:100%; /*background-image:url('images/bgbody.jpg') ; background-size:cover;*/ 
    /* margin-left:300px; overflow-x:false; */ 
    }

.containermain /* container which i want to make center*/ 
{ 
    float:left; 
    width:1000px; 
    background-image:url('images/bgmiddle.jpg'); 
    /*margin: auto 0; */ 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-size:cover; 
}
```

Comment: in which browser does the `margin:auto` not work and what doctype do you have set for your html document? to get it work cross browser you should use doctype `<!doctype html>`. but anyway without knowing the relevant html and css code it is not easy to guess.

Comment: You can user <center> tag, put your div inside <center> </center> tag.

Comment: @incomplete you should not use `<center>` anymore, it is one of the tags that is marked as _obsolete_.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    i developing website in asp.net .. and in master page this contain..

Comment: You need to post your code for us to help.

Comment: code:  
body 
{
 background-image:url('images/bgbody.jpg');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 padding:0 0 0 0;
 } 
.main                                   /*main container*/
{
 float: left;
 margin: 0 auto ;
 width: 1550px;
 /*float:left;
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
/*background-image:url('images/bgbody.jpg') ;
 background-size:cover;*/
/* margin-left:300px; 
 overflow-x:false; */
}

Comment: .containermain          /* container which i want to make center*/
{
     float:left;
    
    width:1000px;
    background-image:url('images/bgmiddle.jpg');
    /*margin: auto 0; */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:cover; 
  }

Comment: Please use the "edit" button below your post to add code to the question (I have done it for you this time).  However, we still need to see the relevant portion of your HTML code to be able to accurately answer the question.  Please use the "edit" button to add that as you soon as you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by adding the following piece of CSS code:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/h5j7B/30/

But you can implement it differently if you have some container for your text inside `div`.

### Edit 1

you need to change as follows

```
.main {
 float: left;
 margin: auto 0;
 width: 1600px;
}
```

Comment: its not working sir,,,

Comment: and if added margin-left:300px then white space is increases at right side.. then how to overcome this problem?

Comment: have you gone through the link http://jsfiddle.net/h5j7B/30/ change and save it according you condition and provide me your link

Comment: ya gone.. i sent link on hishekhar1@gmail.com..

Comment: code:  
body 
{
 background-image:url('images/bgbody.jpg');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 padding:0 0 0 0;
 } 
.main                                   /*main container*/
{
 float: left;
 margin: 0 auto ;
 width: 1550px;
 /*float:left;
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
/*background-image:url('images/bgbody.jpg') ;
 background-size:cover;*/
/* margin-left:300px; 
 overflow-x:false; */
}

Comment: .containermain          /* container which i want to make center*/
{
     float:left;
    /*margin: auto 0; */
    width:1000px;
    background-image:url('images/bgmiddle.jpg');
    /*align:center;*/
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:cover; 
  }

Comment: remove `float:left;` add `margin:auto` in `.containermain` class

Comment: its working now .. but additional white space is cmg at right side..

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a width for your div block if you use margin: 0 auto.

Answer (score 0):

This makes the div at center without margin,

```
 <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0;     right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000;">

<div style="border-width: 0px; position: relative; padding: 50px; background-color: #FFFFFF; top: 49%; color: #333;">Content</div>
</div>
```

For position stuff please check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
and
http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position

Comment: <div style="border-width: 0px; position: relative; padding: 50px; background-color: #FFFFFF; top: 49%; color: #333;">Content</div>    this is working but after main container(width:100%) white space is added..

Comment: Please remove the background-color property

Comment: .main                                   /*main container*/
{
 float: left;
 margin: 0 auto ;
 width: 1550px;
 /*float:left;
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
/*background-image:url('images/bgbody.jpg') ;
 background-size:cover;*/
/* margin-left:300px; 
 overflow-x:false; */
    
}
.containermain                     /* container which i want to make center*/
{
     float:left;
    /*margin: auto 0; */
    width:1000px;
    background-image:url('images/bgmiddle.jpg');
    /*align:center;*/
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:cover; 
  }

Comment: body 
{
 background-image:url('images/bgbody.jpg');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 padding:0 0 0 0;
 }